# PHP foreach loop JSON

Tags: php, json

I know there are like hundreds similar questions on this site, but I just can't get my code working...

I have this JSON

```
{
"version":"1.0.0",
"buildDate":20131029,
"buildTime":165127,

"lockPath":"..\\var\\lock",
"scriptPath":"..\\var\\lock",
"connections":
[
{
    "name":"o016561",
    "bez":"GEW-NRW",
    "type":"OVPN"
},
{
    "name":"o016482",
    "bez":"GEW-BW",
    "type":"OVPN"
},
{
    "name":"o019998",
    "bez":"GEW-SH",
    "type":"OVPN"
}
]}
```

how can I access the "name" values to check if there's an existing file with an equal name?
I tried

```
$json_config_data = json_decode(file_get_contents($json_path,true));

    foreach($json_config_data->connections as $connectionName)
    {
        if($connectionName->name == $fileName)
        {
            $status = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            $status = 0;
        }
    }
```

but I always get `$status = 0`...
I think there's an easy solution for this, but I'm pretty new to PHP so I'd be glad for any kind of help.
Thanks in advice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're resetting the value of `$status` for every iteration which means that the last connection HAS to be the correct one. You're probably looking for a `break` statement.

```
$json_config_data = json_decode(file_get_contents($json_path,true));

$status = 0; //Default to 0
foreach($json_config_data->connections as $connectionName)
{
    if($connectionName->name == $fileName)
    {
        $status = 1;
        break; //End the loop
    }
}
```

Comment: after reading your post, it all makes sense now. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This would only result in `$status == 1` if the final name matched your requirements; otherwise you're setting `$status` back to `0`. You should break out of the loop when you find a match:

```
$status = 0;

foreach ($json_config_data->connections as $connectionName) {
    if ($connectionName->name == $fileName) {
        $status = 1;
        break; // this breaks out of the foreach loop
    }
}
```